# Problems with update query

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net, sql-update

I cant figure out why the update query below doesn't executes, any suggestions:

```
 static public void updateSelectedMainNewsImage(int newsID, string filename, string replace)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand updateNews = new SqlCommand("Update newsImages SET [newsImage] =@filename where [newsID] =@newsID AND [newsImage] =@replace", conn);
    updateNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = newsID;
    updateNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  filename;
    updateNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replace",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = replace;

    updateNews.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What does the database table schema look like? Also, are you getting an error message?

Comment: No i m not getting errors , but its not updating the db

Comment: Without symptoms, it's hard to tell, but I'd guess that the values `newsID` and `replace` don't match any existing rows.

Comment: Table name = newsImages , Columns = imageID(primary Key) , newsID(ForeignKey) , newsImage(string)

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler when this executes and see what gets sent to the SQL Server? I'd do that and then try and execute the same query in Mgmt Studio and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not erroring then it IS working. None of the records are meeting your WHERE conditions.

Comment: The same query is running fine on sql server

Comment: Yes, but data there must be different :) If you're saying there's no error, then the update IS running fine, just doesn't find what to update

Comment: You will need to print out your query string to see what the difference is

Answer (score 1):

you are using                                               `updateNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  filename;`

try to replace this with

`updateNews.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename",filename,SqlDbType.VarChar);`

it's because parameter.addwithvalue function does not need value property be set it has an overloaded version like above.i hope if this can help